# Why can I pass partially applied type constructors only in type parameter position?

Tags: haskell, higher-kinded-types, unification, higher-order-types

This is probably a silly question but I cannot figure out the underlying rules for the following behavior:

```
foo :: t (f a) -> f a b -- accepted
foo = undefined

bar :: t [f a] -> f a b -- rejected
bar = undefined
```

It makes perfect sense that `f` applied to `a` and `a b` respectively in `bar` leads to a kind error and is thus rejected. But why is `foo` accepted?

Comment: `t` can have kind `(* -> *) -> *`, so perform a mapping to a concrete type. For a list that is impossible, since the list has kind `* -> *`, and this thus means that `f a` should be a "concrete" type.

Comment: Consider `data T container = T (container Int) (container String)`, a type which is parametric over container types and holds a container with `Int`s inside and a container with `String`s inside, and `type F = (,)`, a family of containers, one for each metadata type, that tags a single contained element with some metadata.

Comment: You need to be able to do this to use monad transformers, if you've heard of them. If not, basically they transform an arbitrary monad into a new monad that has additional functionality (one reasonably common pattern for building complex code in Haskell is to stack multiple monad transformers on top of each other). To do that, they need to take the monad itself as a type parameter, not an applied monadic type (e.g they need to take
 `Maybe`, `IO`, `State s`, etc; not `Maybe Int`, `IO String`, or `State s ()`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the kind of `f`.

Since the return type is `f a b` - i.e. `f` applied to two parameters, - it means that `f :: Type -> Type -> Type`.

But then `f a` is used as a list element - `[f a]` - and list elements must be `Type`, which means that `f a :: Type`, which means that `f :: Type -> Type`.

Mismatch.

---

`foo` works because types can be partially applied. That is, if `f :: Type -> Type -> Type`, then `f a :: Type -> Type`. And then, type `t` is allowed to have a parameter of kind `Type -> Type`, so everything matches.

---

To reiterate the above:

- `foo` works because type `t` may have a parameter of kind `Type -> Type`.
- `bar` doesn't work, because type `[]` (aka "list") must have a parameter of kind `Type`.

Comment: On the term level you cannot pass a function argument to a first order function. The same principle applies to the type level. I anticipated it'd be a silly question. It's all about kinds: `foo :: t f -> t (->) -> f a b` is happily accepted.